# Estimating DIC for a zoib beta regression model

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, jags, rjags

I have the data and code below and would appreciate your help to estimate `DIC` (or `AIC`) for a beta regression model with `zoib`:

```
library(zoib)
data("GasolineYield", package = "zoib")
re.md <- zoib(yield ~ temp | 1 | 1, data=GasolineYield, 
joint = FALSE, random=1, EUID=GasolineYield$batch, 
zero.inflation = FALSE, one.inflation = FALSE, 
n.iter=3200, n.thin=15, n.burn=200)
sample2 <- re.md$coeff
summary(sample2)
```

Following the package's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoib/zoib.pdf) and the [article](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-019/RJ-2015-019.pdf) published by the authors, I implemented the code below to get `DIC`, but I get an error:

```
dic.samples(sample2, n.iter=201, thin = 1, type="pD")
Error in nchain(model) : Invalid JAGS model object in nchain
```

I ran the same code with an object from `coda.samples {rjags}` documentation and it worked:

```
data(LINE)
LINE$recompile()
LINE.out <- coda.samples(LINE, c("alpha","beta","sigma"), n.iter=1000)
summary(LINE.out)
dic.samples(LINE, n.iter=201, thin = 1, type="pD")
```

Then I checked the class of each of the objects above `LINE`, `sample2`, `re.md`, and `LINE.out`, and the output is:

```
class(LINE)
"jags"
class(re.md)
"list"
class(sample2)
"mcmc.list"
class(LINE.out)
"mcmc.list"
```

This suggests that my error is probably because the object `sample2` is not of class `jags`.

Therefore, I would appreciate any ideas on how I can get `sample2` in a form that can be accepted by `dic.samples`  in order to be able to get `DIC` (or `AIC`) for my `rd.md` model.

Comment: According to the documentation for `dic.samples`, the first parameter is a jags model object. So you are correct, `sample2` is not the correct type. Can you clarify what you are asking as you said it works when you give `dic.samples` a jags object. Does it not give the DIC when it works ?

Comment: Thanks, @steveb. It seems that I need to convert `sample2` into a `jags` object in order to get `DIC` for my `rd.md` model.

Comment: The reason for that is that as you say `dic.samples` seems to only accept `jags` objects, and does not accept `mcmc.list` objects like `sample2` or `LINE.out`. So, please, @steveb, share your ideas on how that conversion can be accomplished. I would appreciate very much.

Comment: I don't have an answer at this point, I just noticed you were not giving the correct type to `dic.samples`.